# template ostream operator overload for stl map

Tags: templates, dictionary, namespaces, overloading, ostream

head.hpp

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>
namespace ns
{
      typedef std::map<std::string, int> StrIntMap;                  
      template<typename T1, typename T2>
      std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const std::map<T1, T2>& map);
};
```

head.cpp

```
#include "head.hpp"
template<typename T1>
std::ostream & ns::operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const ns::T1& map)
{
    for (ns::T1::const_iterator it = map.begin();
        it != map.end(); ++it)
    {
    stream << (*it).first << " --> " << (*it).second << std::endl;
}
    return stream;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "head.hpp"
int     main(int, char **)
{
    ns::StrIntMap bla;

     bla["one"] =  1;
     bla["two"] = 2;
     std::cout << bla << std::endl;
     return (0);
}
```

This code gives following error on compliation:

```
main.cpp no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << bla' 
note C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\ostream.tcc:63 candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&(*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>] 
note C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\ostream.tcc:63                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&(*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>] 
note C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\ostream.tcc:63                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base&(*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
```

**please suggest how to remove this ambiguity**

Answer (score 0):

I will only explain the problem(s), but without further information from your side it is hard to come up with a solution.

The first problem is that the `operator<<` declared in the header is not implemented. The implementation you added in `head.cpp` has a different signature and since it is not declared in the header, `main.cpp` will never find it.

The second problem is that even the declared `operator<<` will not be found. You *might* think that you can rely on ADL to find it, but that only works if `bla` is a type in the same namespace. But `ns::StrIntMap` is a `typedef`, not a type itself and hence it is equivalent to `std::map<std::string,int>`. ADL will only look into namespace `std` for candidates, not in namespace `ns`.

One option I see is to replace the typedef with a real type:

```
struct StrIntMap : std::map<std::string,int>
{
    // C++11 allows you to inherit all ctors from the base class:
    using std::map<std::string,int>::map;
};
```

and try to implement an `operator<<` just for that.